# How to stop the animation of UITextField.rightView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, rightview

On my UITextField the rightView property animates in (slides in) from the left when it's shown.

I'm unsure how to stop this behaviour from happening?

Answer (score 20):

I had this happen recently on iOS 8.

It turns out that the initial position of the `rightView` was at (0,0) relative to the `UITextField`, and when it is being displayed for the first time, it is then set to its correct location. If the keyboard is being displayed at the same time, the position of the `rightView` somehow get animated together with the animation of the keyboard. You can see this clearly in the simulator if you turn on "Slow Animations" (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).

The solution is to set the `rightView` to its final position before the keyboard animation starts. For example, in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, call:

```
textField.rightView.frame = [textField rightViewRectForBounds:textField.bounds]
```

Swift:

```
textField.rightView?.frame = textField.rightViewRect(forBounds: textField.bounds)
```

Comment: Mine need to set this in layoutSubview() because my custom view is instantiate with rect size (0,0).

Comment: Dumped this in layoutSubviews() and solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iOS 14.4. Still animating in with the keyboard animation

Answer (score -2):

you could play around with `rightViewMode` property

```
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

There are following modes available:

```
UITextFieldViewModeNever,
UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing,
UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing,
UITextFieldViewModeAlways
```